# Properly read integer in a range in C

Tags: c

I wanted to write a C function C99/POSIX compliant that read an integer from the user input. I wanted this function to be safe and robust but I feel it is way too complex for such simple task.

I am wondering whether this code is optimal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/**
 * Read an integer from `stdin`.
 * @param min Minimum accepted value
 * @param max Maximum accepted value
 * @param nom Default value
 * @return captured integer
 */
int read_integer(char *text, int min, int max, int nom) {
    int n = nom;
    bool failure = false;

    do {
        printf("%s [%d] ? : ", text, nom);

        // Read user input
        char line[24];
        do {
            if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != line || feof(stdin)) {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                break;
            }
        } while (strchr(line, '\n') == NULL);

        // Default value?
        {
            char *cursor = line;
            while ((*cursor == ' ' || *cursor == '\t') && *cursor != '\0') {
                cursor++;
            }        
            if (*cursor == '\n') {
                return n;
            }
        }

        // Not a number ?
        if (sscanf(line, "%d", &n) != 1) {
            printf("Error: this is not valid entry!\n\n");
            continue;
        } 

        // Not in the range ?
        if (n < min || n > max) {
            printf("Error: value should be between %d and %d!\n\n", min, max);
            continue;
        }

        return n;
    } while(true);
}

int main() {
    do {
        printf("You said %d\n", 
            read_integer("What's the answer", 10, 50, 42));        
    } while(!feof(stdin));
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't look to be working like intended.

Comment: Could you be more explicit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

regarding:

```
if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != line || feof(stdin))
```

This is unnecessary messy.  Suggest:

```
if( fgets( line, sizeof( line ), stdin )
```

If any error occurs, the returned value is `NULL` so the body of the `if()` will not be entered.

regarding:

```
if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != line || feof(stdin)) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            break;
```

the `break;` will never be executed because the call to `exit()` will have already exited the program.

regarding:

```
while(!feof(stdin));
```

please read: [while(!feof()) is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

regarding:

```
    return n;
} while(true);
```

The `return` is always executed, so this loop will never iterate, looking for a valid input.

regarding:

```
char *cursor = line;
        while ((*cursor == ' ' || *cursor == '\t') && *cursor != '\0') {
            cursor++;
        }        
        if (*cursor == '\n') {
            return n;
        }
```

This `while()` code block will iterate to the end of the array `line[]`, most of the time.  the result will be no number will be extracted.  Suggest, starting at `line[0]` to check for `isdigit( line[i] )` and if true, then extract the number, perhaps using something like: `strtol()`

Comment: We generally prefer not to answer questions that contain code that is not working. I would suggested that you should have picked the part of the code that is not working and comment on that. `(return n; } while(true)`